# Modal dialogue box in javafx on macOS

Tags: java, macos, javafx, nswindow

When running a java application on macOS, is there a way in javafx to use the sheet functionality of `NSWindow`?

Sheet is is a customizable modal pane over the current window that behaves in a certain "mac-ish" way: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/sheets/

I am aware that this behaviour is not natively possible on other platforms, I am looking for an implementation for macOS in javafx similar to `beginSheet()` in Swift:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419653-beginsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nearest thing I could find adapting the `NSSheets` functionality is `JSheet`:

http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/guide/jsheet.html
http://www.randelshofer.ch/oop/jhotdraw/changes/jhotdraw_60b1_vs_7.1/JHotDraw%207.1/org/jhotdraw/gui/JSheet.html